# Im having coding problem with calculating decimal to octal. The ans came out wrong like 43 in decimal = 90 in octal which suppose to be 53 in octal

Tags: mips32, qtspim

.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a number: "
output: .asciiz "\n Your numbers are: "
.align 4
myArray: .space 40
.text
.globl main
main:

while:
beq $t0,40,exit

```
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

#Get the user input after "prompt"
li $v0, 5
syscall

#Store the result in t1, 
#this is temporary so we can make chges to it b4 final
move $t1, $v0

# Display the output.
# Which contains the "Your numbers are: ".
li $v0, 4
la $a0, output
syscall

#octalcalculation, $t2 is octal number
li $t6,0 #remainder, initializing with 0 is just to make it available for use
li $t7,0 #final octal number, same for this
decimalToOctalLoop:
    rem $t6, $t1,8
    div $t1, $t1,8
    mul $t6, $t6,10
    add $t2, $t2,$t6
    bnez $t1, decimalToOctalLoop

# Print or show the numbers.
# The number '1' is for print int
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t2
syscall

sw $v0, myArray

addi $t0, $t0,4 #increment by 4 to index/offset

j while #loop back
```

exit:

li $v0,10
syscall

Answer (score 0):

```
#octalcalculation,
li $t2, 1 #set loop = 1
li $t3, 0 #set remainder = 0
li $t4, 0 #set finalOctalNum = 0
decimalToOctalLoop:
    rem $t3, $t1, 8
    div $t1, $t1, 8
    mul $t3, $t3, $t2
    add $t4, $t4, $t3
    mul $t2, $t2, 10
    bnez $t1, decimalToOctalLoop

# Print or show the numbers.
# The number '1' is for print int
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t4 #The final octalnumber after calculation
syscall
```

Comment: I actually found the answer after long hours of trial so i wanna share this since there isn't much clear reference out there in the internet